# How to line-break a big equation with a big square root term?

Tags: amsmath, alignment, split, multline

I have a big equation which has a square root encompassing a major portion. I need to line-break it into multiple lines in latex. The original code that I have is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \lambda = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\tilde{r}
   \left(\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2\right)^{7/4} \tilde{r_h}}\right)\sqrt{\left(-\left(\left(-\frac{\tilde{r}^2 \left(\tilde{r_h}{}^2+1\right)
   \left(\frac{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}\right){}^{3/2}}{\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\tilde{r}^2+1\right)
    \left(2 \tilde{g}^6 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}
   \tilde{r_h}{}^2+\tilde{g}^4 \left(\tilde{r}^4 \left(\tilde{r_h}{}^2+1\right) \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+6 \tilde{r}^2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}
   \tilde{r_h}{}^2\right)+\tilde{g}^2 \tilde{r}^4 \left(\tilde{r_h}{}^4 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\tilde{r_h}{}^2 \left(-4 \tilde{r}^2
   \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+6 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}\right)-4 \tilde{r}^2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}\right)+2 \tilde{r}^6
   \tilde{r_h}{}^2 \left(-2 \tilde{r_h}{}^2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}-2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}\right)\right)\right)\right)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I tried using `aligned`, `split`, `multline`, with various option like `\biggl`, `\biggr`, `\left.`, `\right.` but none of them seem to work. What is the best way to break such an equation across multiple lines? Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial.

Comment: `$\lambda^2=[square of your expression]$` and divide it like any multiplication.

Comment: When something like this shows up, I rethink my notation. Perhaps write `G^2=g^2+r^2` and `G_h^2 = g^2+r_h^2` to start with.

Comment: Whatever else you do, I believe you should replace all instances of `\tilde{r_h}` with `\tilde{r}_h`..

Comment: @Mico will keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you (a) use symbols -- say, `P`, `Q`, and `R` -- for some of the repeated terms and (b) replace all `\left` and `\right` directives with non-autosizing alternatives. And, do use `[...]^{1/2}` notation for the really large square-root term. Last (and definitely least) I'd replace `\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}` with `\sqrt{1.5}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\TR{\tilde{r}}
\newcommand\TG{\tilde{g}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Put $P=\sqrt{\TG^2+\TR^2}$, $Q=\sqrt{\TG^2+\TR_h^2}$, and $R=\TR_h^2+1$. Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
   \lambda 
   &= \sqrt{1.5} \Bigl(\frac{1}{\TR (P^2)^{7/4} \TR_h}\Bigr)
   \Bigl\{-
   %\Bigl[
   \Bigl[-\bigl(\TR^2 R (Q^2/P^2)^{3/2}\bigr)\big/ \TR_h^2+\TR^2+1\Bigr] \\
   &\quad \times\Bigl[2 \TG^6 P \TR_h^2
   +\TG^4 (\TR^4 R Q+6 \TR^2 P \TR_h^2)
   +\TG^2 \TR^4 \bigl(\TR_h^4 Q+\TR_h^2 (-4 \TR^2 Q \\
   &\qquad +Q+6P) -4 \TR^2 Q\bigr)
   +2 \TR^6\TR_h^2 (-2 \TR_h^2 Q-2 Q+P)
   \Bigr]
   %\Bigr] 
   \Bigr\}^{1/2}
   \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would replace the square root by [ ... ]^1/2, the latter with \frac or even \nicefrac from https://ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac. And then manually break the equation, e.g.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

```
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\left( \frac{1}{\tilde{r}
 \left( \tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2\right)^{7/4} \tilde{r_h}}\right)
\\
\cdot \Bigg[ 
-\Bigg( -
\tilde{r}^2  \left( \frac{\tilde{r_h}{}^2  + 1}{\tilde{r_h}{}^2}\right)
\left(\frac{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}
{\tilde{g}^2 +\tilde{r}^2}\right){}^{3/2}%}{\tilde{r_h}{}^2}
 + \tilde{r}^2 + 1 \Bigg)
\\
\cdot
\Bigg( 2 \tilde{g}^6 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}
\tilde{r_h}{}^2+\tilde{g}^4 \left(\tilde{r}^4 
\left(\tilde{r_h}{}^2+1\right) \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+6 
\tilde{r}^2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}
\tilde{r_h}{}^2\right)
\\
+\tilde{g}^2 \tilde{r}^4 \Big( \tilde{r_h}{}^4 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2
+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\tilde{r_h}{}^2 \left(-4 \tilde{r}^2
\sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+6
\sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}\right)
\\
-4 \tilde{r}^2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2 +\tilde{r_h}{}^2}\Big)+2 \tilde{r}^6
\tilde{r_h}{}^2 \left(-2 \tilde{r_h}{}^2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2
+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}-2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}
+\sqrt{\tilde{g}^2 +\tilde{r}^2} \right) \Bigg) \Bigg]^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure why the bracket error, they seem to be equal in number.

Comment: `\left` and `\right` pairs can not be used when on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

The package `breqn` came in handy in this situation although it caused conflicts with some other packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
    \lambda = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\tilde{r}
   \left(\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2\right)^{7/4} \tilde{r_h}}\right)\left(-\left(\left(-\frac{\tilde{r}^2 \left(\tilde{r_h}{}^2+1\right)
   \left(\frac{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}\right){}^{3/2}}{\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\tilde{r}^2+1\right)\\
    \left(2 \tilde{g}^6 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}
   \tilde{r_h}{}^2+\tilde{g}^4 \left(\tilde{r}^4 \left(\tilde{r_h}{}^2+1\right) \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+6 \tilde{r}^2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}
   \tilde{r_h}{}^2\right)\\
   +\tilde{g}^2 \tilde{r}^4\left(\tilde{r_h}{}^4 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\tilde{r_h}{}^2 \left(-4 \tilde{r}^2\sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+6 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}\right)\\
   -4 \tilde{r}^2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}\right)+2 \tilde{r}^6\tilde{r_h}{}^2 \left(-2 \tilde{r_h}{}^2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}-2 \sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r_h}{}^2}+\sqrt{\tilde{g}^2+\tilde{r}^2}\right)\right)\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```